# What does each part of the `ls -la` output mean?

Tags: command-line, ls

What do the following numbers represent?

[image]

Comment: they are file permissions and properties. perhaps you should have a good readin here https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes

Comment: How many time did you read `man ls`?

Comment: @KenSharp The copy of the `ls` manpage on linux.die.net doesn't actually give all the relevant information. For example, it doesn't state what the timestamp is that's shown, and GNU coreutils documentation says only that it is "*normally* the modification timestamp".

Comment: Though I admit I don't know of any situation in which it's been, say, another timestamp like the status change or creation date.

Answer (score 20):

Let’s take this one to analyse:

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 root    root       4096 Dec 18 16:41 somefile.txt
```

We will split the output for better understanding.

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5  Field6  Field7  Field8  Field9        Field10

-       rwx     rw-     r--     1       root    root    4096    Dec 18 16:41  somefile.txt
```

- **First** field:

  - `-` for regular file, `d` for Directory, `l` for symlink
- **Second**: The **owner** can **read**, **write** and **execute** this file
- **Third**: The **owner's group** can **read** and **write** this file
- **Fourth**: **Other users** can **read**, but ***not*** **write** or **execute** this file.
- **Fifth**: The number of hard links to this file or directories inside this directory.
- **Sixth**: The object's **owner**
- **Seventh**: The object's **owner's group**. All of the users in this group (for example, `root`, `user`, `www-data`, etc.) are affected by the permissions in **field 3**.
- **Eighth** field is the object's size in bytes. Note: `ls -lh` will use `k`, `M`, `G`, `T` etc. for **human readable**. (See `man ls` or run `ls --help`.)
- **Ninth** field: The object's last modified time; for directories this is not inheritive.
- **Tenth** field: The object's name as stored in the filesystem's table of contents

See [understanding the Unix permission model](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml), `man chmod` and `apropos permissions` for more information.

**Note**: Some versions of `ls(1)` also display the **octal permissions**, which are a simple way of using a number to display and store the first through fourth fields.

Comment: The first field could also be `b` for a *block device special file*, `c` for a *character device special file*, `s` for a *socket*, or `p` for a *fifo special file* (aka *named pipe*). You are also missing a field in between the fourth and fifth, where a single character may be appended to the permissions string, indicating *Extended Attributes* (`@`) or *Extended Security Information* such as Access Control Lists (`+`). The third character in field 2/3 can also be `s` or `S`, the third character in field 4 can also be `t` or `T`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag right you are. you can edit that in, if you like

Comment: field5 = the number of hard links to this file. symlinks to a file don't add 1 to this file's 5th field. Try : `touch foo bar` and then `ls -l foo bar` (both will have 1 inode pointing them). then `ln foo baz` ; `ls -l foo bar baz` will show both foo and baz, 2 entries pointing to the same inode (pointing to the content of foo), both have "2" as their hard link number. Then add a symlink: `ln -s foo toto` and still only foo & baz have 2 inodes pointing the same file, toto has 1. In the end, foo & baz will have 2, and bar & toto will have 1 in their 5th field, as both have no hardlinks to them

Comment: Script to calculate permissions: https://github.com/crushedice2000/ext4-imc

Answer (score 4):

The numbers represents:

`1` is the number of hard links

`7160` the file size in bytes.