# Permission denied when deleting empty unity-tweak-tool config folder

Tags: permissions, unity-tweak-tool

Recently I've decided I want to delete the unity-tweak-tool. I've removed the program files, purged related files, but when it came to the empty folder in my .config folder, it says my permission is denied. I can't open it, and I can't delete it. I'm the only person using the computer. Help the newbie?

Comment: You may need to check my permission of my empty folder in my .config, ...and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to permission over the folder. Even you are the only user on your PC this doesn't mean that you are the only user owning files there.

There are many other users which is called service users that may own files and directories.

so you have to check the permissions over this folder, you can use the command `ls -l` in the form:

```
ls -l ~/.config/folder-name
```

refer to my [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/710912/150504) here to learn what the output means.

So now how to delete this folder?

you can use many options:

1. using root permission(sudo)
2. [Changing permissions of the folder](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)
3. [changing ownership of this folder](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lpic1-v3-104-5/)

Here i'll state how to use sudo :

just run the command from your terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.config/Folder-name
```

**NB: Don't forget to replace folder-name with the name of the folder you want to delete**