# What does "+ 3" mean in result of 'ls -al'?

Tags: permissions

Accidentally, when moving to a mounted volume, and typing `ll` (alias for `ls -laF`)

```
:/media/username/DATA$ ll
total 153
drwxrwxrwx  1 username username  8192 Sep  1 20:32 ./
drwxr-x---+ 3 root     root      4096 Sep  3 08:14 ../
drwxrwxrwx  1 username username 12288 Jul 26 22:29 documents/
drwxrwxrwx  1 username username 16384 Sep  2 02:01 downloads/
```

I have this interesting part: `drwxr-x---+ 3`

I understand the part `drwxr-x---`, but what the else part `+ 3` means?

Ps: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 x86

Comment: You mean you're curious about the number between permissions string and owner name?

Comment: For the parts of `ls -l` output explained, see http://askubuntu.com/q/710905, http://askubuntu.com/q/517229 or http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103114 please.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `+` after the normal permission bits indicate a special permission is in effect for the file/directory. The special permission is POSIX ACL (Access Control List).

You can set a ACL rule by using `setfacl` and view the already set rule(s) by `getfacl`.

**Example:**

```
% ls -l foo.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 foobar foobar 206 Aug 28 02:08 foo.sh

% setfacl -m u:spamegg:x foo.sh

% ls -l foo.sh                
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 foobar foobar 206 Aug 28 02:08 foo.sh

% getfacl foo.sh
# file: foo.sh
# owner: foobar
# group: foobar
user::rwx
user:spamegg:--x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Check `man getfacl` and `man setfacl` to get more idea.

As a side note, if you see a `.` inplace of `+`, that's for the SELINUX context.

---

And the `3` after `+` indicates number of hard links the file has. A hardlink is a name for the file (file's inode precisely) so number of hard links indicate number of names the file has.

In your case the entry is:

```
drwxr-x---+ 3 root     root      4096 Sep  3 08:14 ../
```

It's for the parent directory of the current directory (`/media/username/DATA`), so `..` points to `/media/username` directory.

Now, in Linux, every directory has at least two hard links, one is for `.` (current directory, link to itself) and the other is it's entry in the parent directory (name-inode mapping), this was inherited from the Unix.

You have hard link count as 3 for `/media/username`, which means `/media/username` has one subdirectory (default 2 plus one for the `..` entry of the subdirectory). If there were 2 subdirectories, the hard link count would be 4 due to both subdirectories mapping `..` back to the parent.

---

Check `man ls` also.

Comment: That's a directory, so the link count is the number of subdirectories plus two.

Comment: @Kevin Added detailed explanation.

Answer (score 8):

`+` at the end of the permissions string signifies an ACL ([Access Control List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)) permission. You can see exactly what permissions it allows and to which users with

```
getfacl ../
```

or rather

```
getfacl /media/$USER
```

In my case:

```
$ getfacl /media/zanna
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: media/zanna
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:zanna:r-x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

This shows the owner and group and then the unnamed "user" (owner) group and world (others) permissions with an extra entry for the user zanna. The "mask" limits the effective rights for group and named users.

ACLs are an extension to the traditional Linux permissions system that allows permissions to be set for a single user or group, allowing finer control. You can read more about the security reasons for having root own this mount point and the use of ACL permissions in `/media` in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392154/why-are-the-default-permissions-for-media-username-rootroot)

The `3` is unrelated to the `+`. it indicates the number of [hard links](https://askubuntu.com/a/801191/527764) to the file.

Comment: This only explains the `+` though, which signals that ACLs are active for this entry in addition to the traditional permission settings. However, this does not explain the `3`.

Comment: @ByteCommander hah it didn't occur to me they were asking about the 3, thanks!