# permission files option ls -l

Tags: ls

I have problem to access to several files in a same directory.
Printout of ls -l:

1. -rwxr-x---  1
2. -rwxr-x---+ 1

I can access to the second file but not the first one.

What does this "+" means ?
How can I make it works for both ?

Many thanks.

Comment: See [What does "+ 3" mean in result of 'ls -al'?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820554/what-does-3-mean-in-result-of-ls-al)

Comment: Thank you for the link.
Why this is not on all files? Can I delete or deactivate ACL ?
-rwxr-x---  1 kwen NasUsers 15556778835 Sep 29 15:05 File 1
-rwxr-x---+ 1 kwen NasUsers   731701248 Mar  9  2011 File 2

I installed all my ubuntu server and I did not setup ACL...